# Why would one ever want to compile with -O2 instead of -O3

Tags: optimization, g++

We usually compile with `-O2` because `-O3` would "trigger subtle bugs".

For our GCC version `-O3` enables more aggressive inlining which would actually reveal bugs otherwise unnoticed (e.g. use of uninitialized values from functions taking them as reference arguments or out-of-bounds access for arrays). It seems to me this aggressive inlining also allows a more expressive way of coding with smaller functions and `-funswitch-loops` helps keeping variable definitions more local in loops.

Given that bugs in our code are orders of magnitude more likely than compiler bugs and that we use `-Wall -Wextra` without any issues what kind of bugs should we be looking for?

If it matters we use `gcc-4.3.2`. Compile time is not a major issue for us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Size. Of course if size does really matters (sometimes is does, like embedded), one would use `-Os`. But main difference at O3 is the (from you already mentioned) inlining. This can increase the generated code size (but it is faster). Maybe you want speed, but not at all (space) cost? Otherwise  I would see no reason why not to use O3 (except you know of a gcc compiler bug that only occurs in your code at O3, but as long as you dont have an error, you cant reproduce at O2, I would not care).

Comment: Actually depending on cache sizes inlining might make code *slower* from the cache misses inlining entails.

Comment: @ArtB Wouldn't it be the compiler's responsibility to verify that the cache sizes on the platform it's compiling for are sufficiently large for the degree of inlining it should perform? Or am I expecting too much?

Comment: @VF1 What is the cache size of x86? Cache size depends on the system and is not necessarily known to the compiler...

Answer (score 5):

Don't kid yourself that compiler bugs aren't lurking out there to make your life hell.  Here's a [nasty one](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=571572) which cropped up in Debian last year, and where the fix was to fall back to -O2.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I wonder if we should nevertheless go with `-O3` until we hit any issues like flolo suggests though. Even more if a bug could produce such blatantly wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes aggressive optimisation can break code just like you mentioned. If this is a project you are currently working on, then perhaps this is not a problem. However, if the code in question is legacy code that is fragile, poorly written, and not well-understood, then you want to take as few chances as possible.

Also, not all optimisations are formally proven. That means that they may alter the behaviour of programs in undesirable ways.

The best example I can think of is a Java one, but it should illustrate my point about optimisations in general.

It is common to have code like this

```
 while( keepGoing ){
      doStuff();
 }
```

Then value of `keepGoing` gets modified by another thread. Well one optimisation that the JVM will do, is see that `keepGoing` is not modified within the body of the loop, so it "elevates" it and checks *before* the loop, essentially transforming the code into:

```
 if( keepGoing ){
      while( true ){
           doStuff();
      }
 }
```

Which in a multi-threaded environment is not the same thing, but in a single-threaded it is. These are the kinds of things that can break with optimisations. This is a frequent [source](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=1705) of "[Heisenbugs](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html)".

PS- In Java the proper answer is the make `keepGoing` "`volatile`" so it cannot presume cached values and would do what you intend.

Comment: This is indeed a project with lots of legacy code. We use `insure` for the warm & fuzzy feeling. The code has pretty horrible cache and branch-misprediction issues that seem to be mitigated at `-O3`. I just wonder what explicitly to be on the look-out for. Do you have any experiences beyond our own superstition?

Comment: This blog post was what made me weary of optimization: http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=1705 The best example I can think of is a Java one. It its common to have code like this where

Comment: I editted my answer to include an instance of the kind of optimisation that can happen and change the behaviour of code.